# importxml img link of a pop-up

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

i am using importxml on googlesheets to extract data from an ecommerce. I need to take the url of an image opened in a pop-up (click on the first miniature to enlarge the pic), but the div with id'cboxLoadedContent' to take the xpath, appears only after the click on the miniature, suggestions on how to solve it?
thank you in advance

this is the link https://www.buyma.com/item/55232720/

```
=IMPORTXML(A1;"//div[@id='cboxLoadedContent']/img/@src")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following XPath to get the url of the first image :

```
=IMPORTXML(C1;"(//@href[contains(.,'org.jpg')])[1]")
```

Output :

[image: Bag.Url]